# audioRecorderDidFinishRecording not called on the device

Tags: avaudiorecorder

Using Xcode 5.0 and running iOS 7.0.2 on my device.

I am using this kind of code:

```
AVAudioRecorder *audioRecorder;
………
[audioRecorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)5.0];
………
- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
        NSLog(@"audioRecorderDidFinishRecording");
}
```

On the simulator things are OK the method audioRecorderDidFinishRecording fires up as expected 5 seconds after a call to recordForDuration has been made.
On the device though it never fires up. Why could that happen? Any idea?

I have seen similar questions on the net, but not exactly this one and more important no answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else has the same issue. Here is the solution I found:

One needs the following before calling the recordForDuration method.

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
```

Strangely enough this is not an issue on the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

`audioRecorder.stop()` needs to be called as well